# Regex to match a letter, but not if that letter starts the word

Tags: regex

I've been trying to figure this one out at regex101, but no luck yet. I want to match the second 's' in system for instance, but not if the s is at the start of the word. so I want to match the "s" in mos, or answer, but I dont want to match the s in space.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
s*(?<!\W)
```

with couple variations, but no luck yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A negative lookbehind is the way to go. I think you need this:

```
(?<!\b)s
```

Details

- `(?<!...)` - negative lookbehind
- `\b` - word boundary
- `s` - the letter `s` to be matched (will not be matched if there is a word boundary before)

[**Regex101 demo**](https://regex101.com/r/b9M5l1/1).